# JQuery Coin slider not showing images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I've been trying to use coin slider to add it to my web page but I've not been able to see any of the images that I've been trying to add, the problem is that it only shows the description messages, the images appear blank... I would really appreciate your help on this, thank you

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Altius Coaching</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="css/coin-slider.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>


<div id="coin-slider">
<a>
    <img src='ALTIUS COACHING.jpg' >
    <span>
        Description for img01
    </span>
</a>
<a>
    <img src='ALTIUS MEDICAL.jpg' >
    <span>
        Description for imgN
    </span>
</a>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 560, height:300, navigation: true, delay: 5000 });

});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

does "ALTIUS COACHING.jpg" exist on the server? Is it the correct cAsE depending on the server? If all else fails, try removing the space from your html and the filename (or changing it to %20) and try again. According to your source, "ALTIUS COACHING.jpg" exists in the same folder as the html file we're viewing, is this correct?

Can you show us the broken page "live" somewhere?